# Improve washed out blurry composite Landsat 8 image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, imagery, landsat-8, composite

I want to create a composite image using Landsat 8 bands. I followed the steps to do so (creation of virtual layer, high resolution, separate) and adjusted the bands' colors (red 4; green 3; blue 2) and I got a colored map.

However, the map seems washed out and not too sharp. I played with the contrast a bit and the load min/max values. This helped a bit but the image still does not seems as sharp as the one I produced with ArcMap.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions? Is QGIS limited in its image rendering options and I just need to accept it?

I am using QGIS 2.18.4 on a Windows 10 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly due to the gamma value. I know that Arc tends to (annoyingly) adjust gamma by default upon loading an image, but QGIS doesn't.